# How to sum up values divided by comma in a single line of code?

Tags: java

I need to sum up the values divided by comma in a String "2,4,5". Of course, I can do something like:

```
String[] str = "2,4,5".split(",")
int total = 0;
for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
  total += str[i];
}
```

But I wonder if there is more elegant and shorter solution (preferably, of one line of code).

Comment: You can just write the code above on a single line. :) What you're looking after is a single expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to sum the numbers you must first convert the Strings to numbers.

Something like this :

```
int total = Stream.of ("2,4,5".split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

- `Stream.of()` converts the `String[]` to a `Stream<String>`.
- `mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` converts that stream to an `IntStream` (by applying `Integer.parseInt()` to each `String`) that has a convenient `sum()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
Stream.of("2,4,5".split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sum `int` as `Strings`, you have to convert your `String` to `int`, you probably need something like this :

```
String[] str = "2,4,5".split(",");
int total = 0;
for (String str1 : str) {
    total += Integer.parseInt(str1);//Convert your String to int
}
```

If you are using java 8, then the solution of @Eran and @Justas are perfect